# How to achieve object merging through generics in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, oop, generics

Imagine I have a class Number:

```
class Number {
    var val: Double?
}
```

and have two instances of that class, `A` and `B`.
Now imagine I want to merge `B`into `A`through a statement like

```
merge(B, into: A)
```

Now of course I could write the function like this:

```
func merge(from: Number, into: Number){
    into.val = from.val
}
```

But that isn't reusable at all. Is there a way I could write a generic merge class?

***UPDATE***: Although some of the answers offer good and viable solutions, none of them are "generic" enough (generic here is meant in a non-technical way).So looking at the answers, I got some inspiration, and here is the solution I am now considering: make Number a NSObject subclass and declare all the properties that can be merged as dynamic. For example:

```
class Number: NSObject {
    //Put the required init and initWithCoder: here
    dynamic var val: Double?
}
```

Then declaring a protocol that mergeable classes must respect

```
protocol Mergeable: class {
    var mergeablePropertyKeys:[String] {get}
}
```

And then declaring a global function that performs a merge:

```
func merge<U: Mergeable, Mergeable where U.Type == V.Type>(from: U, into:V){
    for property in U.mergeablePropertyKeys {
        V.setValue(U.valueForKey(property), property)
    }
}
```

And I know that this will not work because the arguments to merge are not necessarily `NSObjects`.

- How can I make sure that the arguments to `merge` are both `NSObjects?`
- Can avoid having to specify the names of all my mergeable values by simply obtaining a list of my object's dynamic values?

Comment: What do you mean by generic merge class? A global generic merge function? A protocol that defines a generic merge function?

Comment: Either or, it could be achieved through a protocol I think, Im not quite sure how.

Comment: Are you talking about mapping?

Comment: Using `NSObject` in Swift does mean going in the wrong direction.

Comment: @appzYourLife I feel that way too, but do we see better? This would be very easy if we had good ol' c pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a generic function that uses reflection to merge properties. Reflection is limited in Swift, but it is doable using the [MirrorType](http://nshipster.com/mirrortype/). I have used this method before to build a generic [json parser in swift](https://github.com/lehn0058/SwiftSerializable) - you could do something similar but instead of parsing a json dictionary to properties map your two object's properties.

An example of using reflection to do this in swift:

```
func merge<T>(itemToMerge:T) {
    let mirrorSelf = Mirror(reflecting: self)
    let mirrorItemToMerge = Mirror(reflecting: itemToMerge)
    for mirrorSelfItem in mirrorSelf.children {
        // Loop through items in mirrorItemToMerge.
        for mirrorImageItem in mirrorItemToMerge.children {
            // If you have a parameter who's name is a match, map the value
            // OR You could add any custom mapping logic you need for your specific use case
            if mirrorSelfItem.label == mirrorImageItem.label {
                // To set values, use self.setValue(valueToSet, forKey: propertyName)
                self.setValue(mirrorImageItem.value as? AnyObject, forKey: mirrorImageItem.label!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes the object defining the merge method is a subclass of NSObject (so it can take advantage of NSKeyValueCoding). You could also make this a static method that could merge any 2 objects of any NSObject type:

```
static func merge<T1: NSObject, T2: NSObject>(itemChanging:T1, itemToMerge:T2) {
    let mirrorSelf = Mirror(reflecting: itemChanging)
    let mirrorItemToMerge = Mirror(reflecting: itemToMerge)
    for mirrorSelfItem in mirrorSelf.children {
        // Loop through items in mirrorItemToMerge.
        for mirrorImageItem in mirrorItemToMerge.children {
            // If you have a parameter who's name is a match, map the value
            // OR You could add any custom mapping logic you need for your specific use case
            if mirrorSelfItem.label == mirrorImageItem.label {
                // To set values, use self.setValue(valueToSet, forKey: propertyName)
                self.setValue(mirrorImageItem.value as? AnyObject, forKey: mirrorImageItem.label!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly it only does half the work. It is a brilliant way to get all the property + values of an object, but how about setting them?

Comment: Checkout the deserialize method in the SwiftSerializable git repo. It handles this as well. In your case though you won't be creating a new object - it will just use the one that already exists.

Comment: setValue is what you need - key value coding similar to Objective-C, which is what the deserialize method uses.

Comment: So my class needs to be an NSObject subclass and have 'dynamic var's yes?

Comment: It just needs to be an NSObject subclass. Dynamic is not needed to use key value coding. I wouldn't use them unless there is a specific need.

Comment: If you have multiple inheritance this won't get all the properties without looping over the mirror superview as well checking if each superview has a superview and looping over them each until you hit the NSObject superview. Inheritance like dog: fourleg: mammal: animal: NSObject. I think above will only get you dog properties nothing beyond without a change to handle superviews.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure what you are expecting but there is generic solution:

```
class Number<T> {
    var val: T?
}

protocol Merge {
    func merge(from: Self, into: Self)
}

extension Number: Merge {
    func merge(from: Number, into: Number) {
        into.val = from.val
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the idea of a Merge protocol, but to avoid boilerplate code like that, I'd like the properties that can be merge to be defined in it.

Comment: Instead of into.val = from.val, just mentioning val would be optimal

Answer (score 1):

### Protocol

Lets define a `HasValue` protocol (available only for classes) like this

```
protocol HasValue: class {
    typealias T
    var val: T? { get set }
}
```

### Merge

Now we can define a generic function

```
func merge<U: HasValue, V:HasValue where U.T == V.T>(from: U, into:V) {
    into.val = from.val
}
```

The constraints in the function signature do guarantee that

1. Both params do conform to `HasValue` (therefore are classes)
2. `val` types for both params are equals

### Scenario 1: params have the same type

```
class Number: HasValue {
    var val: Double?
}

let one = Number()
one.val = 1

let two = Number()
two.val = 2

merge(one, into: two)
print(two.val) // Optional(1.0)
```

### Scenario 2: params have different types but their values have the same type

I did not constrain the 2 params of `Merge` to having the same type, I am only checking that the `val` properties of the 2 params must have the same type.

So we could also merge different instances of different classes having val of the same type like

```
class Phone: HasValue {
    var val: Int?
}

class Computer: HasValue {
    var val: Int?
}

let iPhone = Phone()
iPhone.val = 10

let iMac = Computer()
iMac.val = 9

merge(iPhone, into: iMac)
print(iMac.val) // Optional(10)
```

### Scenario 3: params have generic types

```
class Box<S>: HasValue {
    var val: S?
}

let boxOfString = Box<String>()
boxOfString.val = "hello world"

let boxOfInt = Box<Int>()
boxOfInt.val = 12

merge(boxOfString, into: boxOfInt) // << compile error

let boxOfWords = Box<String>()
boxOfWords.val = "What a wonderful world"

merge(boxOfString, into: boxOfWords)
print(boxOfWords.val) // Optional("hello world")
```

Comment: But what happens when I want to merge more than `val`? What if I have an object with 1000 properties that need to be merged?

Comment: *What if I have an object with 1000 properties that need to be merged?* you should break down that object first. it is simply too big to be useful.

Comment: @vikingosegundo you get my point. I don't want to have a protocol for every property I want to merge.